# Minimum of $f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(n^2−nx−y)^2}{2^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

> Show that $$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(n^2−nx−y)^2}{2^n}$$  is defined on $\Bbb{R}^2$, it has a minimum and find for which couple $(x, y)$ the minimum is reached.

The first point is okay, for the second one I tried to expand the square to havea quadratic form whose coefficients are series : but this is not a quadratic form.

I do not know how to continue ? I think it's about distance ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Have you tried first finding a closed form for the series? The sum of the series is a quadratic function of $x$ and $y$ and so is quite easy to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jimmy's response shows how to sum the series to find the polynomial $f(x,y)$, and suggests using standard derivative methods to minimize the function. Here's a hint for a faster way of finding the minimum of $f(x,y)$ without calculus:

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=150-52x+6x^2-12y+4xy+2y^2\\
&=\frac23(3x+y-13)^2+\frac43(y^2+4y+28)\\
&=\frac23(3x+y-13)^2+\frac43(y+2)^2+32\\
&\ge32.
\end{align}$$

$f(x,y)$ will only attain this absolute minimum value of $32$ when the square terms are zero, i.e., when

$$\begin{cases}
3x+y-13=0,\\
y+2=0.
\end{cases}$$

Now solve the system of equations.

Comment: Clever response, +1

Answer (score 5):

Expanding gives us $f(x,y) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}2^{-n}\left(n^4-2 n^3 x+n^2 x^2-2 n^2 y+2 n x y+y^2\right)$

We can show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}2^{-n} = 2$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}n2^{-n} = 2$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}n^22^{-n} = 6$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}n^32^{-n} = 26$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}n^42^{-n} = 150$.

Thus, $f(x,y) = 150-52x+6x^2-12y+4xy+2y^2$.

Now, just take the derivative w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, set them equal to zero, and solve.

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 12x + 4y - 52 = 0$, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 4x + 4y - 12 = 0$

$(x,y) = (5,-2)$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I had a negative sign error in one of the derivatives. I think it's fixed now.

Comment: $$\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}2^{-n} = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}n2^{-n} = 2 $$  How can that be possibly true? Wow, shouldn't the RHS sum be at least some number minutely larger than 2?

Comment: Why should it? The $0$-th term on the left side is larger than the $0$-th term on the right side, so the sum on the left "has a huge head start".

Comment: pardon, but is that not what is stated in the second line of your answer? ;)

Comment: Your first comment was asking how $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n2^{-n}$ could possibly be true. You also asked if the sum on the right should be bigger than the sum on the left. My last comment was addressing this question.

Comment: Apologies, the concept of multiplication by 0 seems to yet be beyond me! Still, very fascinating that these two infinite sums equate to the same thing. I'll see if I can prove it for myself. Thank you for your replies.